# How do I find what Javascript is running on certain events?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, firebug, web-inspector

I'll pick Chrome for this example, but I'm open to a solution from any browser.

Use Case:
I have an update button on my website that is used to update item quantities in a shopping cart. I'd like to allow a user to enter a 0 and click update in order to remove the item. Trouble is, there is some listener in some js function that is denying the ability to enter a 0 and click update (after clicking update the old quantity remains).

My question is, what developer tool can I use to find which js function is running during that event? I don't think that Chrome's inspector does this, and I'm not very familiar with Firebug, but I couldn't find the functionality there either.

I feel that I should be able to inspect js firings just like I do css stylings. Is anyone aware of a tool I may use?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I've had to debug some particularly nasty unseen-cause Javascript issues at my job. Knowing the full depth of developer tools like Chrome's is definitely helpful. It undeniably takes some creativity to find places that might be causing the issue, but a few tips:

### Tracking down event listeners

Under Chrome's Elements view, try Inspect-ing an element (right-click, Inspect); then, on the right side of the developer view, scroll down to Event Listeners. Here you can view what code files have hooked up an event. Often, this will just point you to a middle-framework from the really devious code you're looking for, but sometimes it will point you in the right direction.

### Trapping a DOM modification

Many of the unwanted effects I see are because of something changing some value or attribute on the page that I don't want. Anytime this happens, you can right-click on the element (under the Elements view) and say "Break on..." and the specific scenario you're looking for. When Chrome then hits a breakpoint, you can then look downward in the Stack Trace until you find something recognizable that shouldn't be called.

EDIT after reaching ten votes!

### Trapping a JS object modification

If the change you're interested in is code-internal, not in the UI, things get trickier. What's meant by this scenario is that you know somewhere in the code, something incredibly annoying like the following is happening.

```
company.data.myObject.parameter = undefined;
```

In this situation, you know `myObject` is still the same object, but it's being modified, perhaps unintentionally. For that, I often insert the following bit of code, sometimes just through the developer console at some point before said modification happens.

```
Object.defineProperty(company.data.myObject, 'parameter', {
  set: (val) => {
    debugger;
  }
});
```

This includes an arrow function - you're only using this for debugging and Chrome supports it, so might as well save keystrokes. What this will do is freeze your debugger as soon as some line of code attempts to modify `myObject`'s "`parameter`" property. You don't necessarily have to have a global reference to the variable if you can run this line of code from a previous breakpoint that will have the given object in the locals.

---

Otherwise, if all I'm starting out with is the HTML code, and I want to tie that to Javascript code, I'll often just look for identifying features like "id" elements, and search all JS files in my development directory for it. Normally, I can reach it pretty fast.

Comment: This is great, thank you! I was hoping someone would answer who had extensive experience like this. I think I may have found the spot from your first suggestion. I'll keep looking, but I think the 3 things you mentioned are what I'm looking for. I had never see the "Event Listeners" section.

Answer (score 8):

1. Open your page in Firefox with Firebug enabled.
2. Go to console tab in firebug and click profiling
3. enter 0 in the textbox and click the button.
4. Stop profiling.
5. You will be able to see all the javascript functions which have executed due to your actions. You can view them one by one to figure out which method has caused the mischief.

Answer (score 1):

Go to you code. If you are using jQuery there is going to be a function that will be called with the class or id of that particular update button. Or, if you are using Javascript, there is going to be a function called inside the

```html
<input type="button" name="update" onclick="update()">
```

These are the two ways to look for the function that is being called; there is no software that I know

Comment: Seems kinda sad, doesn't it? Why can't I find the scripts running in a particular instance? Seems necessary.

Comment: Yes it is sad but you can no track js function in your console like you track the php functions calls

Comment: Is there a technical reason why?

Answer (score 0):

Download `Firebug` for `Mozilla Firefox`, open it, click on `Net` and refresh your website. Than, you can see which files are loaded on the page.

If you want to check on errors and what goes wrong with an explanation, than click on `console` and refresh the page once again. You will see the errors and on which line it goes wrong.

Note: in your `console`, you can say `hold` or `stop`, so that the `js` file stops loading. And you can edit the script by clicking on `script` in Firebug. Debugging is simple, as it says on their official page https://getfirebug.com/javascript

Comment: What if there is no error? It runs, but I want to edit it. How then would I find it?

Comment: Than there is nothing the see. If there is no error, than the code is working. Maybe it's not the way you want it working, but than there is no error, so nothing wrong with the code either. Of course there is a chance that the `js` file is not loaded, that's why I said check `net` first.

Comment: Of course there can be something wrong with the code: it's giving an unwanted result. Don't you use debuggers to inspect why certain unwanted outputs are happening, even if there is no error?

Comment: Thank you; how do I find the file it's in?