# Inspecting 3D on HTML canvas from Web browser

Tags: debugging, web, 3d, webgl, reverse-engineering

I am trying to determine what technology is used for the 3D model loaded on [this page](http://www.lolking.net/models?champion=266&skin=0). By using the Chrome Dev tools I am able to see the textures loaded on the Network tab. However, on the HMTL you only see the canvas element, which does not tell much. Setting breakpoints does not seem to work since the element does not change from an HTML perspective. How can I determine which script/code is working on the canvas?

As an extra question, does anybody know if WebGL is being used? Or a hint of which technologies and data formats (X3D...) are likely used for this.

Comment: Why the -1? I was expecting some help similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087209/how-do-i-find-what-javascript-is-running-on-certain-events....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is using webgl. Get the [webgl inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webgl-inspector/ogkcjmbhnfmlnielkjhedpcjomeaghda?hl=en)  and run it. If the website is displaying 3D models its probably using webgl.

As for the input data format, no idea, but the webgl inspector gives your the raw data uploaded to the gpu so it should be fairly easy to get the model data. From what I seen im guessing its using positions, normals and uvs interleaved together into one array buffer for the model.

Comment: One way to do it is to inject your own javascript into the canvas methods before the other scripts are run. For example, change `HTMLCanvas.getContext` to something like `function(args){console.log("getContext is called"), return HTMLCanvas.getContext(args)}` Or run a script to get all the scripts being run in the page and filter the irrelevant ones. Or run the profiler to see which functions are called in each frame and go from there.