# How to found which script is run when i click anywhere in website?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Actually, I am working on a WordPress website and I use a theme for it. The problem is that daily I open first time my website and click anywhere in the body it open google ads in new browser window like facebook, jabong and all. So how to remove that. And also after every cleaning browser cookies and history process same issue, I get. Please let me know how to fix it and how to determine what function run when I click?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: refer to [How do I find what Javascript is running on certain events?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18087209/6521116)

Comment: Is it possible to alert name of which function is called?